# How to update the heightForRow from UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, rubymotion

The way my current design works is I dequeue a cell and give it a story id. In the cell `initWithStyle` I create `mysubView` (`UILabel`), set the `autolayout` constraints and fire a `API` request that loads the story title `async`. Then I set the text for the `UILabel`.

The problem is - at this point the `UITableViewController` already calculated the wrong height for the cell because initially the `UILabel` has no `text`. The only way how to update it now is by doing

```
parentTableView.beginUpdates
parentTableView.endUpdates
```

But it feels wrong because I need to reference the parent `UITableView` from within the cell and there has to be a better way. Am I missing something? I'm using `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` by the way for the row height.

Comment: are you set estimatedRowHeight ?

Comment: Yes, I have set it.

Comment: where are you setting estimatedRowHeight ? in my case i set self.view_tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 300;
    self.view_tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension; in viewDidLoad and reload the table after api call .

Comment: did you  try heightForRowAtIndexPath method?

Comment: try using this delegate - (CGSize)systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:(CGSize)targetSize withHorizontalFittingPriority:(UILayoutPriority)horizontalFittingPriority verticalFittingPriority:(UILayoutPriority)verticalFittingPriority

Comment: why dont you complete your api calls and then reload the table.

Comment: @MuhammadZohaibEhsan Because I would like each cell to function as an independent component which loads the data for itself and resize itself. Sort of react-style.

Comment: @balkaransingh estimatedRowHeight is set in the UITableViewController. I can't just call reload table because the call to fetch the label text is done individually in each cell. Each cell fetches the content, so if I have 20 stories, then there are 20 extra http calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you watch [Session 211](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2012/211/) of WWDC 2012, Building Concurrent User Interfaces and apply the concepts there.   This features cells whose contents are independently queried and rendered.

The basic concept is as follows:
1. In `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath`, a cell is instantiated.
2. In the same method, an operation for retrieving the data to populate the cell is created and stored into a dictionary.  A reference to the cell is passed to the operation.   The operation has a completion handler that populates the cell and removes the operation from the dictionary.
3. Before the cell is returned from the method, the operation is added to an operation queue.
4. In `tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath`, operations for cells that have moved off-screen are cancelled and removed from the dictionary.

Comment: This sounds very promising. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

add following code in "cellForRowAtIndexPath" method before return cell.

cell.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
    cell.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()

also You can use only **"updateConstraintsIfneeded"**

Comment: This does not work, because at this point it's to early to update constraints. The cell is returned, but the text for label inside it is loaded with a REST call 1 second later.

Comment: So use dynamic function like heightForView and call on cellForRowAtIndexPath like.

 func heightForView(text:String, lbl:UILabel) -> CGFloat{
        let mylbl : UILabel = UILabel(frame: lbl.frame)
        mylbl.numberOfLines = 0
        mylbl.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
        mylbl.font = lbl.font
        mylbl.text = text
        mylbl.sizeToFit()
        return mylbl.frame.height
    }

On a cell 
heightForView(cell.yourlabel.text!, lbl:cell.yourlabel)+75)

Comment: Sorry, you are missing the point that at the time this method is called there is no text yet available, so I can't calculate the height. But when the text is finally there - the height is already wrong. It is not known to me when the text for the label finally arrives.